# Open sites selected from the top bar in the same tab

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, top-bar

All browsers make it easy to open links in a new tab/window if that's what you want (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click / <kbd>Shift</kbd>-click), whereas opening a link in the same window when the link itself is determined to open in a new one is generally not possible, as far as I'm aware.

I keep SO as a pinned tab in Firefox and see switching sites as a feature of the application, rather than as navigating somewhere else - particularly now that the top bar is even more obviously a shared element across sites. It'd be handy if switching to a different site reused the same tab, rather than opening a new, non-pinned one every time - which I could achieve anyway with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click if I *really* wanted another tab open.

Comment: If I click on a site name in the SE logo drop menu, it opens in the same tab. Do I miss something?

Comment: So you are asking for a feature that is already there?

Comment: If you really don't want to stay on the same page after opening the link, then middle-click on the tab to close it.

Comment: @Oded Hmm, apparently I am. The behaviour is different when the tab is pinned though.

Comment: @shambulator - sounds like a FF issue then ;)

Comment: @shambulator Then it's probably your browser who needs a `feature-request` :D

Comment: `Stack Exchange -> Firefox Meta`. <opens in new tab> D'oh! :)

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is different for pinned tabs. I'm on Max OS X El Capitan.

**Firefox 50.1.0**

- Links to the current community are opened in the same tab.
- Links to other communities are openend in a new tab.

[image: SO Menu in Firefox]

**Safari 10.0.2**

- Links to *.stackexchange.com are opened in the same tab.
- External link to stackoverflow.com is opened in a new tab.

[image: SO Menu in Safari]

**Summary**

I can confirm that in regual (not pinned) tabs all links open in the same tab. Is there a way for SO to fix this so that all links open in the same pinned tab, or is this browser-specific?

Comment: I'm using Chrome latest and everything in that menu opens for me in the same tab.